# How can I run an excel enabled event macro across all open sessions in excel?

Tags: vba, excel

VBA newbie here.

I have an excel spreadsheet that is locked for formatting. However, if you paste into the spreadsheet, the format copied is then pasted into the locked worksheet. I'm using the code below to create an event in excel to undo and paste special values.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

If Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy Then

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Application.Undo
    Target.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End If

End Sub
```

This works perfectly, however, this only works if I am copying and pasting within the same excel session. How can I get this to work across all excel instances?

Thanks!
Dan

Comment: Open up task manager. If you're seeing 2 EXCEL.EXE processes, they cannot talk to each other via the object model. `Application` refers to the current instance, and there's nothing in the object model that refers to anything in any other instance. Short answer: you can't. Why can't the source and destination workbooks be in the same Excel instance?

Comment: It is possible to write your worksheet change function into the sheet module of the other workbook.  See Chip Pearson's "    Sub AddProcedureToModule()" over at http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

Comment: @Mat'sMug This is a template we're trying to send out to users that they will be able to edit themselves. Our hope is that they'll be in the same session but we wanted to see if it was possible to cover them using another instance as well. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: @JohnMuggins I'll take a look. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score -1):

Paste this into the Thisworkbook module of the same file (assuming that moduleis currently empty!):

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub App_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy Then

        Application.EnableEvents = False

        Application.Undo
        Target.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Set App = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set App = Application
End Sub
```

Comment: I deleted my code and pasted this in the ThisWorkbook module. Then saved and closed out excel. It still didn't work when pasting data from a workbook in a different session. Is there something I'm forgetting? Or are some of the replies correct that this can't be done? Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: If you would remove the test for CutCopyMode you'd see it works, but then the code will fire for any change. Problem is, when you copy from outside of Excel, Application.CutCopyMode does not equal xlCopy but equals zero.

Comment: Ok I'll give it a try. Thanks for your help.